# MAMP: permission denied on some computers but not all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp, chmod

A friend and I are using MAMP to develop a site. On my computer I can access CSS files in any folder under our /application root directory. On his computer, many of them have permission forbidden.

We did `CHMOD 755` and checked that his htaccess wouldn't be restricting anything. What else could cause this difference in permissions?

Error:

```
GET http://mysite.loc/application/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js 403 (Forbidden) wefinance/:26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure the higher level permissions are properly set as well (higher level is enforced first). Also did you sudo when setting the permissions?

Ensure permissions are set properly for the www group.

Make sure your apache is configured to allow the connection, as well.